# Cloud map not working with service consisting of multiple tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Hey I am rather new to aws and I came across a problem. I have 2 services that communicate with each other. I've been reading about cloud map and I am confused about couple of things.
So as far as I know cloud map doesnt have its own load balancer, so if I want to have couple instances of those services I need to use loadbalancer anyway, if I have to use loadbalancer anyway whats the point of cloud map?All I can get form map cloud is ip's of services and I can do some client side balancing, but cloud map in this case feels like its useless , am I thinking right?